# Class variable access in all class method

Tags: python, class, instance

I want to have a class variable, so that the value can be access in all instances, but I also want to access the variable in methods inside the class. Is that possible? I have tried this, but it didn't work at all.

```
class myClass:
   myvariable = 1

   def add():
      myvariable+= 1

   def print1():
      print myvariable
```

I want to make two instances, one only do add method, the other only do print1 method

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, just access the variable on the class object:

```
class myClass(object):
    myvariable = 1

    def add(self):
        myClass.myvariable += 1

    def print1(self):
        print myClass.myvariable
```

or if you want to set it per sub-class, use `type(self)`:

```
class myClass(object):
    myvariable = 1

    def add(self):
        type(self).myvariable += 1

    def print1(self):
        print type(self).myvariable
```

The difference is that the latter will create a separate attribute on any subclass when set, masking the base class attribute. This is just like setting an attribute on an instance would mask the class attribute.

Although you can *get* the class attribute via `self` as well (`print self.myvariable`), explicit is better than implicit here, and avoids accidentally being masked by an instance attribute of the same name. Setting class attributes always has to be done on the class; setting it on `self` would create or update an instance attribute instead (not shared).

Do inherit your classes from `object` though; using new-style classes has many advantages, not in the least that `type(self)` will then actually return the class. In old-style classes (not inheriting from `object`) you'd have to use `self.__class__` instead.

Using `object` as a base also gives you a third option, class methods with the [`@classmethod` decorator](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#classmethod); use these when you only need to access the class object, not the instance. These methods are bound to the current (sub)class, so their effect on class attributes is the same as using `type(self)`:

```
class myClass(object):
    myvariable = 1

    @classmethod
    def add(cls):
        cls.myvariable += 1

    @classmethod
    def print1(cls):
        print cls.myvariable
```

Comment: Don't you forgot `self` in methods?

Comment: @MauroBaraldi: I did indeed.

Comment: Or, even easier, you could just access the class variable via `self`.

Comment: @Marcin: no, you cannot *set* when accessing on `self`. And if you have both an instance and a class attribute, you definitely need to access it directly on the class. And then there is explicit being better than implicit.

Comment: Ah, I missed that this is about mutating shared variables.